# Can I use user defined table type for large data insertion?

Tags: sql-server

I have around 50000 records in my DataTable,i tried to use user defined table type as a parameter in my stored procedure.anyway its taking too much time for insertion and my application got hanged.

Can anybody suggest me ,how do i approach this?
What i have tried?

```
User defined table type:
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TYPE_INSERT_EXCELDATA] AS TABLE(
    [MERCHANT] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DEAL_ID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [MODEL_NAME] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [PRODUCT_URL] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [LINE_RENTAL] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IMAGE_URL] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CATEGORY_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BRAND] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PRICE] [float] NOT NULL,
    [NETWORK] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [TARIFF_NAME] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [CONTRACT_LENGTH] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [MINUTES] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TEXTS] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DATA] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [GIFTS] [nvarchar](250) NULL
)
GO


PROC:
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SET_PRODUCT_EXCELDATA]
      @TblExcelData TYPE_INSERT_EXCELDATA READONLY,
      @OUTPUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

     BEGIN TRY
      INSERT INTO GLB_M_EXCELDATA(MERCHANT, DEAL_ID, MODEL_NAME,PRODUCT_URL,LINE_RENTAL,IMAGE_URL,CATEGORY_NAME,BRAND,PRICE,NETWORK,CONTRACT_LENGTH,TARIFF_NAME,MINUTES,TEXTS,DATA,GIFTS)

      SELECT MERCHANT, DEAL_ID, MODEL_NAME,PRODUCT_URL,LINE_RENTAL,IMAGE_URL,CATEGORY_NAME,BRAND,PRICE,NETWORK,CONTRACT_LENGTH,TARIFF_NAME,MINUTES,TEXTS,DATA,GIFTS FROM @TblExcelData
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
      INSERT INTO TBL_LOG(ERRORMESSAGE,PROCEDURENAME,CREATEDDATE,ERRORNUMBER) VALUES(ERROR_MESSAGE(),ERROR_PROCEDURE(),GETDATE(),ERROR_NUMBER());
      SET @OUTPUT='FAILURE';
      END CATCH

END
```

Comment: Time of insertion significantly depends on how many indices you have on GLB_M_EXCELDATA table. Deactivate them before insertion and activate after.

Comment: @DimaSUN sir, I dont have any indexes for this table.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s thank you , i do follow next time. ;)

Comment: @King_Fisher, a TVP should not take significant time for 50K rows.  I've seen TVP insert rival SqlBulkCopy for insert performance. Is the insert being blocked by concurrent activity? An important detail is to specify the actual maximum length of string columns in the DataTable.

Comment: @King_Fisher how do you populate your `@TblExcelData` parameter?